# Command symfony with setContainer in Controller

Tags: symfony

I have a symfony 4 command, and I'm going to connect them with an input entity Project

I moved Command under a rep (src / Appbundle / Service / CloneProject)
then in the controller i have setcontainer to modify the contents of the input to id of my project but there is a

```html
namespace App\AppBundle\Service\CloneServiceCommand;
public function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
       
        $projectId = $input->getArgument('projectId');

        $project = $this->projectManager->findOneBy(['id' => $projectId]);

        if (!$project instanceof \App\Entity\Project) {
            throw new \Exception('Project not found');
        }
        $output->writeln('<info>Clone project</info>');

        $nameProject = $project->getName();
        $urlProject = $project->getUrl();
        $tokenProject = $project->getTokenProject();

        $pathProject = '/home/ke/WorkSpaceProjects/'. $nameProject ;
        echo $pathProject;

        $process = new Process('git clone https://gitlab-ci-token:' . $tokenProject . "@" . $urlProject . " " . "/home/ke/WorkSpaceProjects/" . $nameProject);
        $process->run();
    }
```

in my controller

```html
    public function postAction(Request $request, Validator $validator)
    {
        $data = $request->request->all();
        /** @var Project $project */
        $project = new Project();
        $validator->validateForm(ProjectType::class, $data, $project);
        //dump($project);
        $project = $validator->validateForm(ProjectType::class, $data)->getData();
        //dump($project);
        $projectId = $project->getId();
        $command = new CloneService($this->projectManager);
        $command->setContainer($this->container);
        $input = new ArrayInput(array('projectId' => $projectId));
        $output = new NullOutput();
        $command->run($input, $output);

        $this->projectManager->saveProject($project);

        return new ApiCreatedResponse(['project' => $project]);
    }
```

**my problem is indefinded setContainer in my controllerProject**

Comment: Why don't you define services as services? Or what does `setContainer` do? Does this method exist after all?

Comment: i would recommend to NOT use commands from controllers. Commands and controller do basically the same. They hold the glue-code for services. So just trigger your command from the CLI and your controller from a HTTP requests to let a service do the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register your command in services.yml with tag console.command and you will have access to DI

https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/commands_as_services.html